# Send arrays and strings over a socket with JSON

Tags: python, json, sockets, valueerror

I'm trying to send a string and an int array from a server over a socket to a client in python using json, but I only receive the following error:

`ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 17 - line 1 column 65 (char 16 - 64)`

My current code (that doesn't work):

client:

```
import json
...
msg1 = sock.recv(1024)
msg = json.loads(msg1.decode())

arr1 = msg.get("a")
arr2 = msg.get("b")
```

server:

```
import json
...
arr1 = data #String
arr2 = bulletList #An int array
arr2 = ','.join(str(x) for x in arr2)
x = {
  "a": arr1,
  "b": arr2,
}
             
dataToSend = json.dumps(x)
connection.sendall(dataToSend.encode())
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding `print(msg1.decode())` to see what it's receiving?

Comment: I get multiple records like this: `{"a": "855,600|0,0|", "b": ""}{"a": "855,600|0,0|", "b": ""}`. I guess it's because the send-part of the server code is in a while loop? Or is it because of the buffer size on the receiving end? I know that `loads` can't handle multiple records like that and that's why it crashes. But could I read one record at the time somehow? How should I extract the strings in the client? I'd really appreciate some help, I feel rather lost. @Barmar

Comment: You need to design an application layer protocol that allows you to detect message boundaries. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.